# Google Chrome Launches Internet Explorer on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer, trojan

I recently had a nasty trojan on my box have one problem that has persisted after getting rid of it using Microsoft Security Essentials. Launching the `chrome.exe` executable results in `iexplore.exe` being launched instead. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling chrome several times to no avail.

**Question:**
What could be causing `chrome.exe` to launch `iexplore.exe` and how can I fix it?

**edit**: I believe the main trojan was `Win32/Alureon.DV` which made use of a lot of other trojans/viruses to cause problems. I can give an extended list of all the stuff that Microsoft Security Essentials found if anyone thinks that will help.

Comment: Even double-clicking on "chrome.exe" inside its directory (C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application) results in IE opening?

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake here is trying to clean an infected system.  The best thing to do when you're computer is infected is to back up your data, reformat your drive, re-install your operating system and apps from the original media, and then restore your data.  Anything else leaves you open to the possibility that you only removed *part* of the malware, and there's still a keylogger/password sniffer or something similar still running, just waiting for the chance to steal your online banking password.   [Soon, not even this will be enough](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/bios-virus-rootkit-security-backdoor,7400.html).

Comment: Um, the trojan was really limited to what it could do on my system. I run as a standard user and have UAC enabled. I also did a full-scan on all of my drives which allows you to also check the MBR.

Comment: If it was able to replace your chrome.exe file, it obviously got a lot deeper than you thought it did.  And that's the problem with malware.

Comment: @Joel Coehoom Chrome resides in the User directory. So it is entirely possible that it could have modified that executable even without Administrator privileges. So no, I don't think it got a lot deeper than he thought it did. I think it got just as deep as he thought, but it's just that you don't need to go any deeper to modify Chrome.